# Perform onClick outside the onCreate

Tags: android, fragment, onclicklistener

I have a button, on which, i'm trying to `perform Click ();` outside on Create

its a fragment so what i have done is:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private Button exit;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false); 
        exit = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.exit);

        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {.............. });

       return rootView;
    }
```

and i have a method

```
public void clicker(){
    exit .performClick();
}
```

i manually call clicker method from another class, but  it throws

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean android.widget.Toggle Button.performClick()' on a null object
>   reference

Comment: Is your `Fragment` inflated when you call `clicker()` method from the other class? Also, why do you want to do it that way? It's not a good practice.

Please you should refactor your code and take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: how about put getView().findviewid() in onActivityCreated?

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be to put whatever your onClick does in a method and then call that method instead of exit.performClick

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.Toggle Button.performClick()' on a null object reference
```

This error means you are trying to click `exit` button but it is not initialized. You can't do click if view is null.

Best way is , check view is created, initialize the button and then perform click operation.

Another thing is `MyFragment` is a fragment and you can access any objects inside this fragment via `Interface`. Just declare an interface, implements this interface into that fragment , call this interface method from outside this fragment.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a space between exit and performClick(). exit is probably a keyword and may that is why the code compiles.